# SELECT QUERY WITH COUNT()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In this query there is an error:

```
"Column 'upload_news.upload_time' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
```

I want to display number of records that are related to distinct country with country name between two dates;

```
select count(Distinct news_id) AS TotalRecords, country 
from upload_news 
group by country 
having [upload_time] between GetDate()-2 AND GetDate()
```

Comment: Why can't it be in the where clause?

Comment: having should be from the aggregate function not an independent or isolated column.

Comment: The error message explains it perfectly.  You're misunderstanding what the `HAVING` keyword is used for.

Comment: And what about GetDate??

Comment: can you give me any idea that can solve my problem @MikeChristensen

Comment: Sure.  What happens if you change `HAVING` to `WHERE`?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near where @MikeChristensen

Comment: Put the `WHERE` *before* the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @user3419496 - Glad to hear!

Comment: Can you give me any idea that now i want delete all records that are affected by this query. @MikeChristensen

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? If `GetDate` is defined then it's probably Sql Server.

Comment: @user3419496 - Please post a new question.  But you can probably do something like `DELETE FROM Foo WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Foo WHERE ...)`

Comment: Yes me using sql server 2008 R2

Comment: @user3419496 - I've updated the tags.  In the future, please tag questions with the database you're using so you don't get a bunch of MySQL answers.  Also, I've added my answer below if you want to *Accept* it and give me a few points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause will run *after* all the data is grouped, thus you can only filter on aggregations of grouped data.

If you want to filter out rows *before* the data is grouped, you need to use the `WHERE` clause:

```
select count(Distinct news_id) AS TotalRecords, country 
from upload_news 
where [upload_time] between GetDate()-2 AND GetDate()
group by country
```

Note, the `WHERE` clause needs to go *before* the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select count(Distinct news_id) AS TotalRecords, country 
 from upload_news 
group by country 
having [upload_time] between GetDate()-2 AND GetDate()
```

Should be:

```
 select count(Distinct news_id) AS TotalRecords, country 
 from upload_news 
 where upload_time between (NOW()- INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND NOW()
 group by country
```

Comment: now the error is: 'NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name. @Robert Rozas

Comment: Then you are not using `MySQL`.